# Why InputStream methods are not abstract?

Tags: java, methods, inputstream

The java.io documentation says InputStream methods like close(), mark(), available() and others are not abstract. However, according to Java documentation, they don't do anything in the default implementation. My question is: Is there a reason for it? I mean, if this methods do nothing by default, obviously I'll have to rewrite them if I decide to create an InputStream subclass. So, in my vision, making these methods abstract would be more correct, since if we don't do that I can easily forget to rewrite one of these methods and it will not work correctly.

Comment: it probably would be more correct for some which you will almost always override (close), and not useful for others which you may never override (mark/available).  why does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of not making them abstract is precisely so you *don't* have to put in empty method bodies if you're not going to support optional operations. "Doing nothing" is different from "having a default behavior", which in the case of `InputStream` varies from actually nothing (`mark` is a no-op, since marks aren't always supported) to throwing an exception to indicate inability to perform the requested operation (`reset`). Any stream that *doesn't* provide those facilities will use this same behavior, and any stream that does support them will have to override with the specific implementation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a method as abstract in a class ensures that a subclass must provide implementation of the abstract method otherwise the subclass shall be made an abstract class. So there is not such necessary for the sub-class of Inputstream class to provide the implementation of that methods.